# why does the function passed to replace not have parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

Why when passing a function to the last parameter of `replace`, does that function not take parenthesis?

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string){
  // p1 is nondigits, p2 digits, and p3 non-alphanumerics
  return [p1, p2, p3].join(' - ');
};
newString = "abc12345#$*%".replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you added parenthesis, you would be evaluating the function expression named `replacer`.

Instead here you're passing a variable named `replacer`, which is a reference to the function. Instead of executing the function right away, you tell Javascript's `replace` to use it *later*, when it's called natively.

One metaphor I think of sometimes, is that you are handing over a gun for someone else to fire, you're not firing it yourself. `replacer()` means "fire the gun right away", whereas `replacer` means "here, use this to fire". The expectation here is that JavaScript's native `replace()` function will "load the gun" with bullets (parameters), and then fire it when ready.

Comment: this is as opposed to passing a reference to the function

Answer (score 0):

There is a little nuance here that might be difficult to grasp at first.

If you were to add parentheses, you would be indicating you want `replacer` to be invoked right then and there. That's not actually what you want to do.

`replace` is actually looking for a reference to a function, so you're actually passing in the function as an argument to `replace`. Internally, `replace` knows when and where to properly invoke `replacer`.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use a function name with parentheses, f(), you are to call the function and using the results. When you use without parenthesis, f, if means you are using the function itself. If it helps, think of it as you want to use reference the code of the function, not the value it returns.

In your example, you are not calling the function replacer and passing the value to replace. You are passing a chunk of code called replaced to the function replace for the function replace to call it whenever it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaSCript a function is an object like any other.  It can be assigned to a variable, passed to a function, returned from a function, etc.

In this case the reference to `replacer` is being used as a variable here:

```
newString = "abc12345#$*%".replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer);
```

*The function itself* is being passed into the call to `replace`.  (Which will likely execute that function internally, at least under some condition.)  If the parentheses were added like this:

```
newString = "abc12345#$*%".replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer());
```

Then instead of passing the function itself as an argument, you'd be passing the result of the function as an argument.  The result of that function appears to be a string.  However, the function you're calling doesn't expect a string, it expects a function.  (Passing it a string will likely fail when it tries to "execute" that string.)

Comment: I think OP's confusion is that replacer expects parameters and the callback doesn't appear to send them. Just a guess cause I wondered that when I first saw this as well.

Comment: @KaiQing: Potentially.  Though we don't see where `replacer` is being called, so we don't see if it's receiving parameters or not.  In this case I would assume that `replace` internally supplies them to the callback.

Comment: @KaiQing yes, that's it exactly. How is it getting those parameters?

Comment: @thomas: When it gets called inside of `replace`, the line that calls it is sending the parameters it needs.  All you're doing is telling the code to `replace` which function to call, it handles actually calling it.  (You can probably look in the source code of `replace`, wherever it's defined, and see.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a `callback`.

If you call `replacer()`, you'll be running the `replacer function` with no parameters.

In this case, replace function asks for a `callback as the second parameter`, and replace method will call the given callable parameter itself.

Think it like this, you can do something like this within replace function:

```
.replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, function() {
    //You can write replacer's code here as a closure
});
```

Instead of defining a closure like this, you're telling replace function to call replacer function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `replacer` is a function pointer.  Just as you can have pointers to instances of variables you can have pointers to functions.  If parenthesis had been placed after `replacer` such as `replacer()` then `replacer` would be evaluated as the function itself.  Instead what you are doing is passing a pointer to the function `replacer` which can then be called by the function `replace`.

In c++: A common use of an alternative of this pattern is function object / function pointers.  In which the struct / object has the operator () overloaded to make it act like a function.  But most languages have a version of these whether they be called functors, callbacks, function pointers or whatever.